# Setting string value through substring operator in Informix?

Tags: sql, sql-update, websphere, informix

I have to migrate an Informix DB to PostgreSQL DB and I'm looking for the documentation of a function, but I can't find anything.

My Issue - I have this line of Informix SQL:

```
update tab1 set mycolumn[7, 10] = "abcd";
```

I assume mycolumn gets the "abcd" from character position 7 to 10 and the rest of mycolumn remains untouched. But I have to verify it; that's the reason, why I need the documentation. Original IBM documentation would be the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the IBM Informix 14.10 documentation for the [UPDATE SQL statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=statements-update-statement) follow the links for the **SET Clause** and then **Single-Column Format** and **Expression** where there is a link to the [Column Expressions](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=expression-column-expressions#ids_sqs_0195). On that page is a description for the [first, last] syntax which is described as an Informix extension.

Here is an example:

```
create table tab1(mycolumn char(12));
insert into tab1 values("123456789abc");
update tab1 set mycolumn[7,10] = "ABCD";
select * from tab1;
```

with the result:

```
mycolumn

123456ABCDbc
```